# Javascript Array Destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays

Noticed an interesting behavior of Javascript while playing with Array Destructuring 
eg:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [one, two, three, four = 4] = a

console.log(one, two, three, four)
console.log(b)
```

When I say `a.length` **output** is `3` 
If I say `b.length` **output** is `3`. 
However, if I say `four` **output** is `4`. 
If `four` is an element of `b` then why `b.length` is shown as `3` why not as `4`?

Comment: Because you set b to a, which is [1,2,3] (len 3)

Comment: Thanks @Dino for your instant reply.
Yes, I got that part, however, As I have added one more additional element in variable b and when I am accessing it, it is giving me a correct output. 
That's why bit confused, when its holding the value then why its not showing it correctly when we say b.length.

Comment: the construct `a = b = c` is equivalent to `b=c, a=c` **not** `b=c, a=b`. This means in your case `[one, two, three, four=4] = a; let b = a;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this `let b = [one, two, three, four=4] = a` **does not** create a new array with four elements to assign to `b`.

if you do `let b = [one, two] = a`, you would still get `b.length` `3` because it assigns the value `a` to `b` without any modification.

remember, you're simply using de-structuring and default assignment feature in here -> `[one, two, three, four=4]` which does not create a new array.

if you do `a === b`, you will get `true`.

Answer (score 2):

`four` is not an element of `b` (which is `a`). You're using the default value `=4` feature there; it's not getting assigned into `b`.

Running your code through the Babel REPL, to de-sugar that destructuring, gives us something like:

```
var _a, _a$;

var a = [1, 2, 3];
_a = a;
one = _a[0];
two = _a[1];
three = _a[2];
_a$ = _a[3];
four = _a$ === void 0 ? 4 : _a$;
var b = _a;
```

As you can see, `b` eventually just gets assigned `_a`, which is `a`; the destructuring assignments occur "in-between".

Answer (score 1):

Assignment works right-to-left, and when something is assigned to with `=` (whether by destructuring or not), the *whole expression* on the left and right of the `=` is equivalent to the value of what was assigned (on the right hand side).

There is no intermediate array with

```
[one, two, three, four=4] =
```

Rather, that's just assigning to existing variables, without creating an additional expression (other than `4`, which is assigned to `four`).

```
a = [1,2,3];
let b = [one, two, three, four=4] = a
```

is like

```
a = [1,2,3];
let b = (() => {
  [one, two, three, four=4] = a;
  return a;
})()
```

In your code, `b` is the *exact same* array as `a`:

```js
a = [1,2,3];
let b = [one, two, three, four=4] = a;

console.log(b === a);
```